# How to show loading image when to send an email in wpf application

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

Basically I send an email by clicking on send button. While clicking on send button, I want to show a loading image and it (the image) should automatically hide after the email was sent.

Comment: and you want to provide some code about what you have tried or ? And what you are looking for is a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49853/Better-WPF-Circular-Progress-Bar.aspx). I think it works for you. Just change visibility of progress bar according to sending mail and its completion.